# Having issues with a shiny app and rmarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

Yall... heres the deal. I am writing shiny app in rmarkdown and my code is working when I go line by line and even when I run the chunk for the data processing. Yet when i launch the document it gives me this error:

```
Warning: Error in $<-.data.frame: replacement has 1 row, data has 0
  146: stop
  145: $<-.data.frame
  143: eventReactiveValueFunc [<text>#299]
   99: nodes
   98: shinyRenderWidget [<text>#16]
   97: func
   84: renderFunc
   83: output$SBBgraph_net
    3: <Anonymous>
    1: rmarkdown::run
```

I have been at this issue for days with no idea on where the error is because as I said.. when I go line by line as it is written with no changes it works and produces the graphs perfectly. Any ideas on where to start? I am at a loss. And yes everything is updated.

Comment: Can you share that bit of code where the error is happening? `Reactive`-values behave differently, so it is not unusual to have that debugging behaviour you are describing.

Comment: And please. Only that bit that is related to the error. The `ui` and `server` part, please.

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved this today! My reactive inputs were not being read as numbers like they should've been!

Nothing an as.numeric function couldn't fix!